# How to change URL structure of specific page via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change this URL:

```
http://example.com/reman-rewards.html
```

to:

```
http://example.com/remanrewards
```

From `reman-rewards.html` to `remanrewards` without the dash (`-`) and without the  extension (`.html`)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my co-worker was able to provide me with the solution to this question.

The solution is:

```
RewriteRule ^remanrewards/?$ reman-rewards.html [NC,L]
```